# Cannot make when condition working with Yup validation schema

Tags: typescript, yup

I'm having some troubles creating a schema validation with a condition using Yup :

```
import {
  object, string, 
} from 'yup';

const formValidationSchema = () => object().shape({
  someInput: string().required('Some error Message'),
  someInput2: string().required('Some error Message 2'),
  someInput3: string().required('Some error Message 3'),
  someInput4: string().when('someInput2', {
    is: 'Some string value',
    then: string().optional(),
    otherwise: string().required('Some error Message 4'),
  }),
});
```

My IDE is complaining with the following error : `TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

It looks like it is trying to use this signature for the `when` method :

```
when(builder: ConditionBuilder<this>): this;
```

When it should be using this one :

```
when(keys: string | string[], options: ConditionConfig<this>): this;
```

I also tried using an arrow function in the `is` param since it is the line underlined by my IDE :

```
  // ... 
  someInput4: string().when('someInput2', {
    is: (someInput2) => someInput2 === 'Some string value',
    then: string().optional(),
    otherwise: string().required('Some error Message 4'),
  }),
```

No succes there neither.

Comment: "I  also tried using an arrow function in the is..." - Please show because for me it works without errors: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzhARgKwKYGMYA0cAzjFMAHYDmRFAriOtlEgL5wBmUEIcA5AE86YPgG4kSXBAqlO0EADUAhgBtgAEyUxg0gMq4AFthBK4AXjgAKAJTmAfGix4YNgHTEDSsNkvJUxHmwASQowOhgALhIySio3KGwARzpgBPVLPl1AuGZuKDgAWWxiYiUqbD5rAhQSQJCwmAAmKNJyaniklLSMrJBsHKg8wuLS8rhGyur-OtDwgGYWmPbrVwTk1Ox0zOzc6GGSsv65yZqAvvrwgBYo+kZmNwB3IwoM4GIAIWAqPiI-VDg3lEyHRsFN-jBnlFLMRDMYlLYzA4YUYTK4QJRLABWKo1VAQCHMB5vbBQ5FwhFI2Go9EvAAMONQrBxTNEQA

Comment: Edited with the code I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `yup` package TypeScript code, this is the typing of `ConditionConfig`:

```
type ConditionConfig<T extends ISchema<any>> = {
    is: any | ((...values: any[]) => boolean);
    then?: (schema: T) => ISchema<any>;
    otherwise?: (schema: T) => ISchema<any>;
};
```

Obviously as you can see your code does not match this type, because you don't provide a function on both `then` and `otherwise` keys.

For example, if I just do this arbitrary code, I get no TypeScript error:

```
import {
  object, string, number
} from 'yup';

const formValidationSchema = () => object().shape({
  someInput: string().required('Some error Message'),
  someInput2: string().required('Some error Message 2'),
  someInput3: string().required('Some error Message 3'),
  someInput4: number().when('isBig', {
  is: 'Some string value',
    then: (schema) => schema.min(5),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.min(0),
  }),
});
```

Comment: You are right, my bad, it seems that `then` and `otherwise` are supposed to be a method with the current schema in parameter returning the target schema.
I got misled by an old SO answer that probably used an older version of Yup..
Thanks for your input !